# How to limit GeoServer memory usage?

Tags: geoserver

How can I limit the memory usage of GeoServer (v.2.21.1) installed on a Windows Server 2019?

I can't find any setting in the interface to set a limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way as any other Java program by setting a JVM option `-Xmx756M` for example. See the GeoServer manual for [recommended best practices](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html#optimize-your-jvm)